# How do I get the name of a PyQt "enum" constant?

Tags: python, pyqt5, constants

For actual Python enum-type variable `x`, it is possible to get the name of the constant using `x.name`.

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class State(Enum):
    inactive = auto()
    active = auto()
    completed = auto()

state = State.active
print(state.name)
```

> active

I'm trying to get the equivalent for PyQt5 [QProcess.ProcessState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#ProcessState-enum) which is initially a C++ enum, but has been coded as a full class in PyQt.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess

process = QProcess()
state = process.state()
print(type(state))
print(state)
print(str(state))
print(repr(state))
```

> <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QProcess.ProcessState'>
> 0
> 0
> 0

This instruction:

```
print(state.name)
```

produces:

> 'ProcessState' object has no attribute 'name'

I have two questions: Do this process state have anything to do with a Python enum? How can I get the textual representation instead of the integer value?

Comment: use `enum = enum_mapping(QProcess, QProcess.ProcessState)` `print(enum[process.state()])`. Note: In PyQt6 the Qt enums are python Enum so the workaround is no longer necessary.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Thanks. I assume you mean the enum_mapping defined in the linked question, consisting in creating a dictionary of name-value pairs.